# Query for JSONB column in Hibernate using nativeQuery

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm using Hibernate 6.2.17, postgres, and spring-boot 3.1.7.

I've got a DB table like:

```
       Column        |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id                  | bigint                 |           | not null | 
 sd_id               | bigint                 |           | not null | 
 day                 | date                   |           | not null | 
 attributes          | jsonb                  |           |          |
```

I want to aggregate the values in the json objects by their keys across rows in the table, and have a native query to do so:

```
  @Query(
      nativeQuery = true,
      value =
          """
      SELECT sd_id AS sdId, json_object_agg(key, val) AS attributes
      FROM (
          SELECT sd_id, key, sum(value\\:\\:numeric) val
          FROM pr, jsonb_each_text(attributes)
          WHERE pr.day BETWEEN :startDay AND :endDay
          GROUP BY sd_id, key
      ) s
      GROUP BY sd_id
      """)
  List<PRCustomStatistics> getPRCustomStatistics(
      LocalDate startDay, LocalDate endDay);
```

The issue is that the only way I've got this to work is with this DTO:

```
public interface PRCustomStatistics {
  long getSdId();
  String getAttributes();
}
```

Where `attributes` is a `String`, and not any kind of JSON representation. For example, `attributes` might have the value `'{"f1":10,"f2":20}'`.

What can I do so that I can return `attributes` as a `Map<String,Double>` or any other kind of structured data rather than a `String`?